# How does one find the equivalent of this expansion of a summation formula?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

For the summation with the form 1 + 4 + 9 + 16.. n^2 (don't know how to write it in sigma form on keyboard, sorry) does anyone know how we derive its equivalence which is n(n+1)(2n+1)/6? My textbook gives it as a definition, but it doesn't show how to actually use algebra and get to it. Would help me a lot if someone can explain to me how or is it because the process is very long so the textbook just defines it?

Comment: [Derivation on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number#Derivation_of_the_summation_formula)

Comment: [Same question here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/600199/derving-the-formula-of-a-summation?rq=1)

Comment: Slide 15 of this [link](http://math.berkeley.edu/~rbayer/09su-55/handouts/ProofByPicture-printable.pdf) gives a 'proof without words' in lieu of algebra.

Answer (score 3):

There is more than one way to do this, but you could start with the expression
$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}[(i+1)^3-i^3]$.

If you write this out term-by-term, you get

$[(n+1)^3-n^3]+[n^3-(n-1)^3]+[(n-1)^3-(n-2)^3]+\cdots+[3^3-2^3]+[2^3-1^3]=$

$(n+1)^3-1^3=n^3+3n^2+3n$.

We can also write this sum as 
$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}[(i+1)^3-i^3]=\sum_{i=1}^{n}[3i^2+3i+1]=3\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2+3\sum_{i=1}^{n}i+\sum_{i=1}^{n}1=3\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2+3\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+n$,

so solving $n^3+3n^2+3n=\displaystyle3\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2+\frac{3n(n+1)}{2}+n$ for $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2$ should give this formula.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I made this graphic a few months ago. The method is to stack squares (e.g. 25,16,9,4,1), and then try to figure out what needs to be added to make a perfect cube (in this case $5^3$
).

Using the graphic as a guide, we can generalize
$$5^3=3(1+4+9+16+25)-2(25)+(1+2+3+4+5)-5$$
to
$$n^3=3\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^n k^2\bigg) - 2n^2 + \bigg(\sum_{k=1}^n k\bigg) - n$$
$$n^3=3\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^n k^2\bigg) - 2n^2 + \frac{n(n+1)}{2} - n$$
$$n^3=3\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^n k^2\bigg) - 2n^2 + \frac{n(n+1)}{2} - n$$
$$6\sum_{k=1}^n k^2=2n^3+4n^2-n(n+1)+2n$$
$$6\sum_{k=1}^n k^2=2n^3+3n^2+n$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$ n^3+3n^2+3n=[(n+1)^3-1]=\sum_1 ^n[(x+1)^3-x^3]=3\sum(x^2)+3\sum(x)+n\\$$
Therefore, 
$$ 3\sum(x^2)=n^3+3n^2+3n-3(\sum(x)+n)\\=n^3+3n^2+3n-(3/2)n(n+1)-n\\=n^3+(3/2)n^2+(1/2)n\\=(1/2)n(n+1)(2n+1)
$$
Therefore, $$ \sum(x^2)=(1/6)n(n+1)(2n+1)
$$

Answer (score 1):

Another way of solving this problem involves the Hockey Stick formation of Pascal's Triangle.

[image]

Notice how the number in the *blade* of the pink hockey stick is the sum of the numbers in the *shaft* (e.g. 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1=8). Similarly, the blades of the blue and peachy hockey sticks follow that same pattern.
$$28 = 1+2+3+4+5+6+7$$
$$56=1+3+6+10+15+21$$

You can prove this property easily with induction, but i won't get into that here.

I'm particularly interested in the peachy hockey stick, because the blade portion represents the sum of the triangular numbers. I can rewrite the sum as follows
$$56=1+3+6+10+15+21$$
$$\binom{8}{3} = \binom{2}{2}+\binom{3}{2}+\binom{4}{2}+\binom{5}{2}+\binom{6}{2}+\binom{7}{2}$$
$$\binom{8}{3} = \sum_{k=2}^{7}\binom{k}{2}= \sum_{k=2}^{6+1}\binom{k}{2}$$

I wrote $7$ as $6+1$ because $\displaystyle\binom{8}{3}$ is the result of adding 6 items together.

Now, I'm ready to make the generalization

> $$\binom{n+2}{3} = \sum_{k=2}^{n+1}\binom{k}{2}$$

$$\binom{n+2}{3} =\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}k(k+1) = \frac{\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}k^2-k}{2}$$

$$2\binom{n+2}{3} =\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}(k^2-k)=\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}k^2-\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}k$$
At this point I would like to change my indices from $k=2\dots n+1$ to $k=1\dots n$.
$$2\binom{n+2}{3} =\bigg((n+1)^2-1^2+\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2\bigg)-\bigg((n+1)-1+\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\bigg)$$
$$2\binom{n+2}{3} =(n+1)((n+1)-1)+ \sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2 - \sum_{k=1}^{n}k$$
$$2\binom{n+2}{3} =n(n+1)+ \sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2 - \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
$$4\binom{n+2}{3} =n(n+1) + 2\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2$$

$$2\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2 = 4\binom{n+2}{3} - n(n+1)$$
$$2\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2 = 4\cdot\frac{(n+2)(n+1)(n)}{3!} - n(n+1)$$
$$6\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2 = 2(n+2)(n+1)(n) - n(n+1)$$
$$6\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2 = n(n+1)((2n+2) - 1)$$
$$6\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2 = n(n+1)(2n+1)$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$

As an exercise, try finding $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^3$ by using the identity
$$\binom{n+3}{4} = \sum_{k=3}^{n+2}\binom{k}{3}$$

As a bonus exercise, show that the sum of the numbers in the green squares is
$$\sum_{k=1}^{20}k^3$$
Then use those results to derive a formula from $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^3$.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

A tedious but mechanical proof in the spirit of generating functions:

Observe that using the operator $x\,d/dx$ twice on $x^n$ gives
$$\left(x \frac{d}{dx}\right)^2 x^n=\left(x \frac{d}{dx}\right) n x^n=n^2 x^n.$$ Applied to the geometric sum $$\frac{\:\:1-x^{k+1}}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+\cdots +x^k,$$ this gives
\begin{align}
\left(x \frac{d}{dx}\right)^2\frac{\:\:1-x^{k+1}}{1-x}
&=1+x+2^2 x^2+\cdots +k^2 x^k\\
&=x \frac{d}{dx}\frac{x-(1+k)x^{k+1}+k x^{k+2}}{(1-x)^2}\\
&=\frac{x+x^2-(1+k)^2 x^{k+1}+(2k^2+2k-1) x^{k+2}-k^2 x^{k+3}}{(1-x)^3}.
\end{align}
The limit as $x\to 1$ then gives the sum of the first $k$ squares. This can be done using l'Hopitals rule three times, obtaining after algebra $$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{1}{6}k(k+1) x^{k-2}\left[(k-1)(k+1)^2+(2 + k) (1 - 2 k - 2 k^2) x + k(6+5k) x^2 \right]=\frac{1}{6}k(k+1)(2k+1)$$ as required.

Comment: I seem to remember another generating function approach which gives this more elegantly. I'll see if I can dredge that up.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to get this formula that is fairly straightforward:

Start with the difference table for $n^2$,

0 1 4 9 16 25

$\;\;$1 3 5 7 9

$\;\;\;$2 2 2 2

$\;\;\;\;$0 0 0

Using the left diagonal,

$\displaystyle n^2=0\binom{n}{0}+1\binom{n}{1}+2\binom{n}{2}$, so

$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2=0\binom{n+1}{1}+1\binom{n+1}{2}+2\binom{n+1}{3}=\frac{(n+1)n}{2}+2\frac{(n+1)n(n-1)}{6}$

$\displaystyle=\frac{n(n+1)}{6}\big[3+2(n-1)\big]=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}.$